# using grep -E to find peoples last names that begin with S but not include them is their first names begin with S

Tags: grep, data-management

Find people whose last name begins with S in the people.txt file (Your expression should
match the entire last name, not just the initial S, and only capital S qualifies). Ensure that
the first names that begin with S are not included.

the people.txt includes bellow:

```
Cardoza, Fred
Catto, Philipa
Duncan, Jean
Edwards, Neil
England, Elizabeth
Main, Robert
Martin, Jane
Meens, Carol
Patrick, Harry
Paul, Jeanine
Roberts, Clementine
Schmidt, Paul
Sells, Simon
Smith, Peter
Stephens, Sheila
Wales, Gareth
Zinni, Hamish
```

answer should be:

```
Schmidt, Paul
Smith, Peter
```

my answer currently includes:

```
Schmidt, Paul
Sells, Simon
Smith, Peter
Stephens, Sheila
```

pls elp me

Comment: originally my code was grep -E "[^<S]" People.txt

Comment: i then edited it to not include peoples whos first names started with an s which was  "[\<S][a-z][,]\s?[\^<S]"  People.txt @Amadan

Comment: `grep -E "[^<S]"` will find lines that contain any characters that is not `"S"` and not `"<"` (which is a bit strange). Your second one says it must have `"<"` or `"S"`, then any _one_ lowercase letter, then a comma, then maybe a space, then `"^"` or `"<"` or `"S"`. Can you explain what you intended with those? Also, they do not seem to correspond to the output you claim you are getting. CWLiu has given you the solution, but make sure to review regular expressions to understand what his solution means.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E "^S[^,]*, [^S]" People.txt
```

Regex `^S[^,]*, [^S]` would match to the strings which start with 'S' and 'non-S' right behind the comma.